# How to update a json file with keys from another file, only if they already exist in the original?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following two files:

**file1.json**:

```
{
  "error": {
    "200": "200 error",
    "500": "500 error"
  }
}
```

**file2.json**:

```
{
  "error": {
    "200": "200 error code",
    "400": "400 error code"
  }
}
```

When I run the following command `jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' ./file1.json ./file2.json` I get this file:

```
{
  "error": {
    "200": "200 error code",
    "400": "400 error code"
    "500": "500 error"
  }
}
```

But what I want is to update the keys of `file1` with the values of matching keys  in `file2`, and the new keys in `file2` will be ignored. So it would return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "200": "200 error code",
    "500": "500 error"
  }
}
```

Notice that the key `200` was updated with the value from `file2` while the key `400` was ignored.

Comment: What's the goal here? Why are you using `*` or parsing `./fr.json` in the first place? Your desired output is just `./en.json`, so something seems missing.

Comment: @chepner The goal is to add any missing keys that `fr.json` does not have but `en.json` does over the `fr.json` and remove any extra keys that `fr.json` has and `en.json` doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide an example where that isn't just `en.json`?

Comment: I've modified the question. Maybe this makes more sense @chepner

Comment: No, because your output is still identical to `file1.json`. What input do you expect to have *any* difference from `jq '.' file1.json`?

Comment: Do you want to keep the *value* from the second file if it differs from the value of the same key in the first file?

Comment: The second file will keep it's value if it's present in both files @chepner

Comment: Ok, you might want to make that clearer in the question by having `file1.json` and `file2.json` use different values  for the keys they have in common.

Comment: Good point, I edited my question to reflect that @chepner

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to the problem as I understand it:

```
jq -n '
 input.error as $file1
 | input.error as $file2
 | (($file2|keys_unsorted) - ($file1|keys_unsorted)) as $k1
 | ($file1 + $file2) | delpaths($k1 | map([.]))
 | {error: .}
' file1.json file2.json
```

There are many other alternatives....

Comment: I posted a much simpler answer, in case you're interested.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
jq -n '
   input.error as $overrides |
   input | .error |= (
      keys_unsorted[] as $key |
      .[$key] = ( $overrides[$key] // .[$key] )
   )
' file2.json file1.json
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/SKDH7k6_X8) [Example from question]
[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/fB9IbP4RX1) [Example from comments]

(Note the reversed file order.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. [Here is another example](https://jqplay.org/s/vp8QVj8aBY). The goal is to only include keys that are present in file1 in file2

Comment: @bryan Only the keys from file1 are included in the link you provided, so you just showed that it does work. Did you put the files backwards? Remember, file1 is the second file as shown in the answer. I even explicitly brought your attention to this fact in the answer.

Comment: [You can clearly see that it works as requested](https://jqplay.org/s/fB9IbP4RX1) when you put the files in the right order.

Comment: Is there anyway to have this work if you're multiple keys deep?